# Junit for SPRING-MVC Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4

How to write Junit for Spring MVC controller method as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNewApplicant", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String addApplicant(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("applicantData")
ApplicantData data)
{
```

Comment: There is nothing to test. It's an empty handler that does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Not true - you can test mappings (as you have pointed out in your answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to perform requests have a look at Springs MockBuilders.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/DefaultMockMvcBuilder.html

For example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyConfig.class})
@WebApplication
public class MyTests {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Inject
    private WebApplicationContext wac;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void test() {
        mockMvc.perform(
            post("/addNewApplicant")
                .param("key1", "value1")
                .param("key2", "value2")
        ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: this test case not hit controller method and getting Error:- Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]:

Comment: You can change post() to fileUpload() to indicate a multipart request.